# Calculating the second order partial derivatives of $z(x,y.)$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

If we know that $z_{x}^{'} = \frac{yz}{z^{2} - xy },$, how can I calculate the second order partial derivative with respect to x, knowing that the final answer should be (as given at the back of the book) $z_{xx}^{''} = \frac{2xy^{3}z}{(z^{2} - xy)^3 },$. could anyone explain to me how to do it? I do not know from where the power 3 in the denominator came.

Comment: This is a bit strange; you want to find _"the second order partial derivative with respect to $y$"_ but you refer to an answer for $z_{xx}^{''}$, which looks like a second order derivative with respect to $x$...? Do you have $z(x,y)$ as well? Please include all relevant information.

Comment: I am sorry I will fix this mistake @StackTD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we know that $z_{x}^{'} = \frac{yz}{z^{2} - xy }$, how can I calculate the second order partial derivative with respect to x

Take the partial derivative with respect to $x$: use the quotient rule and don't forget that $z$ is a function of $x$ (and $y$). This will then contain the first partial derivative $z'_x$ again, but you can substitute that with:
$$z_{x}^{'} = \frac{yz}{z^{2} - xy }\tag{$*$}$$
and then simplify.

---

Here's a start:
$$\begin{align}z_{xx}^{''}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}z_{x}^{'}
& =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{yz}{z^{2} - xy }\right) \\[6pt]
& =\frac{\left(z^{2} - xy\right)\color{red}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(yz\right)}-\left(yz\right)\color{blue}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(z^{2} - xy\right)}}{\left(z^{2} - xy\right)^2 } \\
& = \ldots
\end{align}$$
Now $\color{red}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(yz\right)}=yz_{x}^{'}$ and use $(*)$ for $z_{x}^{'}$ and don't forget the chain rule for $\color{blue}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(z^{2} - xy\right)}$ and you'll be able to use $(*)$ once again to eliminate $z_{x}^{'}$.